# Issues with ScrollTop in jQuery (mostly in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

So I've been having issues using scrollTop for a website. I've made some test code and I've managed to get it working in Firefox, but it still refuses to work in Chrome... I really can't see what is wrong with the code. I have added a console.log() to show the value of the offset and this works fine, but the Chrome browser doesn't scroll to the div with id="search". Can anyone see anything that I'm doing wrong?

```
<a href="#" id="test-btn" class="darhoudou-button">Test</a>

<div class="test-box">test1</div>
<div class="test-box">test2</div>
<div class="test-box">test3</div>
<div class="test-box">test4</div>
<div class="test-box" id="search">test5</div>
<div class="test-box">test6</div>
```

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#test-btn').on('click', function(){

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#search').offset().top
            }, 200);

        });

        console.log($('#search').offset().top);         
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is the box maybe positioned absolutely?

Comment: Your code works fine in Chrome for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mpa29552/. Check the console for errors in other parts of your code

Comment: As stated, this code does work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jqfps5c4/

Comment: The mentioned code should work fine. May be try posting a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Just now I tested this with chrome and worked. Does your page have enough height? Maybe your Chrome is maximized and FF not?

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm really confused then. I have no console errors, nothing is positioned absolutely, and each div with class="text-box" has height 300px, with parent container having height: auto... As I stated, it works fine in Firefox!

Maybe I will try i jsfiddle!

Comment: @Chris_S, I've rolled back your latest edit because it's inappropriate to post answers in that manner. Please review the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42608687/revisions) for your changes and post the necessary information as an answer (the button is at the bottom of the page). When you have posted your answer, you can then use the checkmark next to your answer to mark it as complete.

Comment: @zzzzBov - Thanks. First time I've posted a question on here!

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it has no problem.

If your browser has height 500px and page 600px, You can only 100px scroll. And if height of page is less than 500px then there is no Scroll.

Please change this `<div class="test-box">test6</div>` to this:

```
<div class="test-box" style="height:1000px;">test6</div>
```

And see the result, Or you can test this snippet with chrome:

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" id="test-btn" class="darhoudou-button">Test</a>

<div class="test-box">test1</div>
<div class="test-box">test2</div>
<div class="test-box">test3</div>
<div class="test-box">test4</div>
<div class="test-box" id="search">test5</div>
<div class="test-box" style="height:1000px;">test6</div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#test-btn').on('click', function(){

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#search').offset().top
            }, 200);

        });

        console.log($('#search').offset().top);         
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Turns out that it was my css file causing the issue... If anyone else experiences a similar issue, I would recommend commenting out any js and css files one by one and see if fixes it. That might help you pinpoint which file is causing the issue...

The problem with my css was the following:

```
 html { 
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}    


body {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```